# Communication between a Laravel front website a Laravel API, both under Valet

Tags: laravel, api, valet

I have two locale installations of **Laravel**, one used as a **front** website and the other as an **API**, both are *parked* with **Valet**. My problem is that it doesn't seem to be able to communicate together, maybe because of Valet. So, I tried the little test below which, for some reason, is not working.

- **Step 1**

I have this code in `routes/api.php` of the **API** website:

```
Route::get('hello-api', function () {
    return 'Hello Api!';
});
```

When opening the URL `http://api.test/hello-api` in my browser, I get "Hello Api!" as expected.

- **Step 2**

Then, when I have the code below in the `routes/web.php` of the **front** website:

```
Route::get('/hello-front', function () {
     return 'foo';
});
```

When opening the URL `http://front.test/hello-front` in my browser, I get "foo" as expected.

- **Step 3**

However, if I replace the code in `routes/web.php` of the **front** website by this one:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

Route::get('/hello-api', function () {
//     return 'hello';

    $client = new Client();

    $response = $client->request('GET', 'http://api.test/hello-api');
    $statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
    $body = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    return $statusCode;
    return $body;
});
```

Then, instead of the expected "Hello Api!", I get the following error message:

```
{"status":"error","errors":["cURL error 6: Could not resolve: api.test (Domain name not found) (see https:\/\/curl.haxx.se\/libcurl\/c\/libcurl-errors.html)"]}
```

What's wrong in my code or maybe in Valet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by adding this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       api.test
```

But I'd be interested to see if it can be fixed in **Valet**.